# Spark unable to parse timestamp fileds

Tags: apache-spark, type-conversion, apache-spark-sql, timestamp-with-timezone

I am creating a Spark (2.2.0) DataFrame by loading from a local file. The file load happens as expected and I get a following DF.

```
scala> df.show(4, false)
+--------+------------------+------------+----------------------------+
|userId  |legacyProductId   |optInFlag   |transaction_date            |
+--------+------------------+------------+----------------------------+
|71844441|805934            |null        |Sat Oct 15 23:35:22 UTC 2005|
|71844441|714837            |null        |Sat Apr 09 10:04:30 UTC 2005|
|71844441|732860            |null        |Sat Mar 19 17:30:26 UTC 2005|
|71844441|1170951           |null        |Sat Mar 19 17:30:26 UTC 2005|
+--------+------------------+------------+----------------------------+
only showing top 4 rows
```

The first two columns are `integer`s, the last two are `string`s. I want to convert the `transaction_date` column to unix timestamp. I did the following.

```
val newdf = df.select($"userId", $"legacyProductId", $"OptInFlag", unix_timestamp($"transaction_date", "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy"))
```

With that, I do get the last column as milliseconds. However, the conversion  does not happen for all the rows, as shown below.

```
scala> newdf.show(4, false)
+--------+------------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|userId  |legacyProductId   |OptInFlag   |unix_timestamp(transaction_date, EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy)|
+--------+------------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
|71844441|805934            |null        |null                                                        |
|71844441|714837            |null        |1113041070                                                  |
|71844441|732860            |null        |null                                                        |
|71844441|1170951           |null        |null                                                        |
+--------+------------------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------+
only showing top 4 rows
```

Only the second row timestamp gets converted successfully. The rest fail and are set to null.

Am I specifying the format string `EEE MMM d hh:mm:ss z yyyy` correctly? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [`hh` is](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> Hour in am/pm (1-12)

You should use `HH`:

> Hour in day (0-23)

like

```
scala> spark.sql("SELECT unix_timestamp('Sat Mar 19 17:30:26 UTC 2005', 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy')").show
// +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |unix_timestamp(Sat Mar 19 17:30:26 UTC 2005, EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy)|
// +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |                                                                1111253426|
// +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```